# App link or Deep link with profile redirection

Tags: android, redirect, deep-linking, applinks

I have a link like http://example.com/user/profile/MJi0aE 
Here MJi0aE is unique user id for redirecting to view particular user profile.

Expecting: 
if i click that link from anywhere in mobile eg:message box,whatsapp inbox it should open app and show user profile screen if already app installed otherwise it should redirect to play store.

Occurs now: 
if i click that link it redirect to app if exist but if app not available means it opens that link in browser and showing user profile in web.

Here is the app link code in manifest file.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/user/profiles/" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in following way, As you are already using following url  `http://example.com/user/profile/MJi0aE`                          which is been declared in your manifest to redirect to app if it exist on phone. As follow

```
<data android:scheme="http"
      android:host="example.com"
      android:pathPrefix="/user/profiles/" />
```

That is correct.

For other situations you need to do redirection of url (**Which is done at server side Redirecting URL**)  to point to your google play app address whenever its been hit in any browser or web-view.

Example if App name is ExtAPP,

`http://example.com/user/profile/MJi0aE`  will redirect to `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.extapp&referrer=test`.

Comment: @Dev : let me know if you need any other help !!